# Check if an index exists in an R vector

Tags: r

I have a simple problem... I would like to check if a specific index exists in a vector in R.

Here are a few examples that need to be satisfied.

```r
#check to see index 18 exists in this vector

empt_vect<- vector(mode = "character")
#Since empty_vect[18] does not exist, return F

large_vect<- vector(mode = "character", length = 100)
#Since large_vect[18] exists, return T

small_vect<- (mode = "character", length = 10)
#since small_vect[18] does not exist, return F
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? I can't seem to find any functions to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would checking if the index is less or equal to the vector length suit?

Comment: Good grief. Yes it would. I don't know why that didn't come to mind initially. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
#check to see index 18 exists in this vector

empt_vect<- vector(mode = "character")
#Since empty_vect[18] does not exist, return F
ifelse(length(empt_vect)>= 18, T,F)

large_vect<- vector(mode = "character", length = 100)
#Since large_vect[18] exists, return T
ifelse(length(large_vect)>= 18, T,F)

small_vect<- vector(mode = "character", length = 10)
#since small_vect[18] does not exist, return F
ifelse(length(small_vect)>= 18, T,F)
```

Comment: No need for the ifelse as `length(small_vect)>= 18` will retrn a logical